# pdf.js in IE 9. Warning: Unhandled rejection: Error: Access is denied

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-9, pdf.js

I receive this error when trying to view the following: http://www.publishers.org.uk/_resources/assets/attachment/full/0/2091.pdf
in IE9, I have pdf.compatibility.js loaded so I don't believe that it's related to type arrays. 
Has anybody encountered this before/understand why it occurs?

Edit:
I'm using the following version

PDFJS.version = '1.0.1040';

PDFJS.build = '997096f';

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot load PDF files from another domain (cross-origin) in Internet Explorer, because the PDF is fetched using XMLHttpRequest and Internet Explorer 9 does not support CORS (Cross-Origin Resource Sharing). CORS was introduced in Internet Explorer 10.

You could work around this issue by loading the PDF from the same origin. Download the file to your own server first by using a back-end proxy on your server, then load the PDF from there.

Comment: Can confirm this is the reason, thanks. I'm now proxying the data through my web server.

Comment: @ChrisSewell Could you please elaborate on the method you are using to proxy the data through your web server? I am stuck with the exact same problem. Cheers!